# Executing CMD File in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, windows, cmd

I wrote a .cmd file that determines a machines windows version and resets any static IP's to DHCP running the appropriate "netsh" command for the OS. I also have a visual basic program that is on all our user's machines to execute different options in our software. I wanted to add a button to our program so users can run this script if we are not able to remote into the computer. This .cmd file does not exist on these user's computers. Is there a way for the .cmd to be saved within and executed from my visual basic program? I know I can run command lines from within VB but this script is a little more complicated than a simple string line can handle without becoming a mess.

[Pic of CMD File code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xzoc.jpg)

```
::Checks Windows Version to know which script to run
@ECHO OFF
FOR /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('ver') do (
IF %%a==XP (goto :dhcpXP) else (goto :dhcpW7)
)
Exit /B

::Resets DHCP for IP and DNS on XP/POSReady2009
:dhcpXP
For /f "tokens=3*" %%a In ('netsh interface ip show config') Do (
Call :UseNetworkAdapter %%a "%%b"
)
Exit /B

:UseNetworkAdapter (
netsh interface ip set address name=%2 source=dhcp
netsh interface ip set dns name=%2 source=dhcp
)
Exit /B

::Resets DHCP for IP and DNS on Windows 7
:dhcpW7
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

SET adapterName=

FOR /F "tokens=* delims=:" %%a IN ('IPCONFIG ^| FIND /I "ETHERNET ADAPTER"')     DO (
SET adapterName=%%a

REM Removes "Ethernet adapter" from the front of the adapter name
SET adapterName=!adapterName:~17!

REM Removes the colon from the end of the adapter name
SET adapterName=!adapterName:~0,-1!

netsh interface ipv4 set address name="!adapterName!" dhcp
netsh interface ipv4 set dns name="!adapterName!" dhcp
)
Exit /B
```

Comment: what about `Shell("path\to\file.cmd", AppWinStyle.Hide)`

Comment: You should include the code as text in your question, not as an image (particularly an externally-hosted image).

Comment: Having such a button is a great way to make system administrators fear you.  Also, consider that in most situations the user does not have the access rights to run such a script.

Comment: @BrianKeller-Heikkila Sorry, I'm new here. I have now added the code to the question.

Comment: @TRiNE, Doesn't that require the "file.cmd" to be on the users system?

Comment: @Mitch, These are Point Of Sale systems so we create the user accounts to be Admin accounts. We are the systems administrators but these registers are located all over the world so we use a remote software to login to the systems and we set static IP's for proper network communication. If the ISP changes their modem in a way that the static IP's can no longer connect we need the end user to set them to DHCP in order for us to be able to access the system. It seems odd but it works for what we have to accomplish.

Comment: @TonyMcAwesome Ok. then what you can do is store your code as embedded text file. When user click the button, read the content and save as a text file with `.cmd` extension in `%temp%`. Then use `process.start("yourfile")` with `runas` as `startArgument`. Then while(existFile) try delete.

Comment: @TRiNE Thank You. I will give this a try today.

Comment: @TonyMcAwesome Yes. Deleting is not necessary. I posted working example as the answer. If you find my effort fruitful please mark it as answer. Then others also can reach it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First add your batch file to project as resources.**

Go to project properties > resources.

[image: Adding resources to VB.NET windows application project]

**Find the working example project from the link**

Run batch file (bat, cmd) or text script using VB.NET 
[Project.zip](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByyTOMaRbWRccG9Sb2VFaHJqUjg)

**Or code is here**

Add a command button to the windows form.

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
Dim program As String = "myprogram"

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim output As String
    output = My.Resources.myprogram
    Dim programPath As String = Path.GetTempPath & “\” & program & ".cmd"
    Using sw As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(programPath)
        sw.Write(output)
    End Using
    If (My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(programPath)) Then
        Dim procStartInfo As New ProcessStartInfo
        Dim procExecuting As New Process

        With procStartInfo
            .UseShellExecute = True
            .FileName = programPath
            .WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal    'use .hide to hide the process window
            .Verb = "runas"                             'run as admin
        End With
        MsgBox("Please press Yes when system ask permissions", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "myProgram")
        procExecuting = Process.Start(procStartInfo)

    End If
End Sub
End Class
```